# PHP FREETDS MSSQL and locale special chars

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, raspberry-pi3, freetds

my Raspberry3 is connected to a Windows MSSQL server, I'm getting lot of troubles updating and inserting strings in MSSQL using ODBC connection (FreeTDS), because some chars (italian) are transformed.
For example this string "Pipe 1m Ø30 cm. max. temp 90 °C" is saved as "Pipe 1m ÃƒÂ˜30 cm. max. temp 90 Ã‚Â°C".
I read a lot on the web, tried to change default_charset in php.ini, set "client dataset" in freetds.conf, also tried iconv() function, but nothing works.

This is a PHP sample code.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');    $odbc=odbc_connect("DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=MyServer\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;UID=myUser;$PWD=myPWD;TDS_Version= Auto;Port=1433;", "","") or die(odbc_errormsg());
$value = 'string with special chars: °±Øòàèé?°§ù end string';
$q="UPDATE MYTABLE set MYFIELD = '$value' WHERE ID = 1";
odbc_exec($odbc, $q) or die("<p>".odbc_errormsg());
odbc_close($odbc);
?>
```

the result is:
"string with special chars: Ã‚Â°Ã‚Â±ÃƒÂ˜ÃƒÂ²ÃƒÂ ÃƒÂ¨ÃƒÂ©?Ã‚Â°Ã‚Â§ÃƒÂ¹ end string"

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Parametrise your query, and use `nvarchar`. The combination of the injection and the `varchar` are the reason why you're getting this. Parametrise with the correct data type and the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Use prepared statements. But if it still doesn't work when you use `$q="UPDATE MYTABLE set MYFIELD = 'string with special chars: °±Øòàèé?°§ù end string' WHERE ID = 1";` it might be a FreeTDS bug.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it would have to be `MYFIELD = N'string...'` but the OP really needs to get rid of that *huge* injection risk. [Little bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, I know about xkcd. I also know that FreeTDS is full of bugs so I'm not surprised international characters are a problem for it.

Comment: Little bobby tables was aimed at the OP, not you, @AlwaysLearning :)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning "FreeTDS is full of bugs" - how so? I've found it to be remarkably reliable over the years. I've been running it since version 0.64. It even does some things that Microsoft's own driver can't (like connecting with Windows credentials). This is more likely a PHP odbc bug than a FreeTDS bug, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

While using parameters is the correct solution, the reason this is happening is that the special characters are being translated to varchar, which has no code point for them.

In this query, the contents of `$value` will be converted to `varchar` single-byte-per-character in the current collation.

```
$q="UPDATE MYTABLE set MYFIELD = '$value' WHERE ID = 1";
```

A unicode `nvarchar` string literal is prefixed with `N`.  EG

```
$q="UPDATE MYTABLE set MYFIELD = N'$value' WHERE ID = 1";
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of the suggested solutions worked, I will try to report the problem to the FreeTDS team.